# Would you like to enter a security context?

Tags: linux, selinux

When I login , it asks me 
"Would you like to enter a security context?"

I have SELinux enabled ..I'm using Fedora 12.
How to resolve this?

Comment: You haven't told us what your problem or questions is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody, the issue is with working of Pam.d with selinux enabled. I turned off pam.d features .its working now. though i need to re-look into /etc/pam.d/login instead of disabling it complete.

I have two choices - 1.disble selinux or 2.disable pam.d for login server. I chose 2.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know this is a decade old answer, but what did you do to disable pam.d for login server?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I made selinux entry as `optional` on /etc/pam.d/login file

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific need for SELinux I would just disable it, as it makes troubleshooting things more complicated.

1) Boot into single user mode:  When you first start your computer, the GRUB screen (where you choose your Operating System) appears. Select the Fedora that you want to boot into, but press the a key instead of pressing Enter.  append 'single' to the arguments there.

2)  Then set SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config

3)  reboot

Comment: I tend to set it to permissive, rather than disabled, because at least that way it logs stuff that has a different SELinux configuration to what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=116395) by adding a < /dev/null